# Make one word lower case using mui sx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI Button element:

```
<Button>Export to CSV</Button>
```

The buttons text currently looks like:

> EXPORT TO CSV

I need the button text to look like this:

> Export to CSV

I tried using

```
sx={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
```

but
`To`
is then capitalised also.

How would I capitalise the first and third word, while leaving the second lowercase, using MUI's `sx` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply remove the default uppercase text transform like so:

```
<Button sx={{ textTransform: 'none' }}>Export to CSV</Button>
```

If you want to do this for every `Button` component within your app, you could set a style override at the Theme level like so:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanks!